# EC2 Instance for Rails + Node.js App

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

What Amazon EC2 instance type should I use for my application built on Rails and Node.js, I need something that can handle many concurrent request, please adise.

Note:

I will use Passenger with Nginx.

Comment: Can you please help me then, where the question with the answer.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but have a look at the top of your question.